# xslt to (i) check if a tag exists & not empty (ii) extract a parent node if one of the repeating child node 'value' contains a string at a position

Tags: xslt

I have an issue with the implementation of following features:

(i) I need to check for a tag in the xml. If it exists and is not empty, I should get it's value otherwise the default value. I am writing xslt like below:

```
<xsl:if test="relation">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="boolean(relation/termId) and string(relation/termId) != ''">
      <xsl:value-of select="relation/termId" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text>DefaultTermId</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
```

So, relation/termId exists and has some value(say `<termId>x</termId>`, I should get x) The xpath and all are fine. It works fine when the termId tag does not exist (=> I am getting 'DefaultTermId') but is returning an empty space when the tag has no value. I mean when is is `<termId></termId>`, I am getting an empty space instead of 'DefaultTermId'. i tried `relation/termId/text() != ''` as well, but no use.

(ii) The other issue is => My xml looks like below:

```
<GetSavedReportResponse xmlns="">
  <ResponseType>Success</ResponseType>
  <FileModifiedDateTime>2012-01-03T17:05:04</FileModifiedDateTime>
  <FileSizeBytes>7816</FileSizeBytes>
  <FileDataFormat>XML</FileDataFormat>
  <FileData>
    <Zthes>
      <term>
        <termId>49555</termId>
        <termUpdate>add</termUpdate>
        <termName>Active Personnel</termName>
        <termVocabulary>People Status Global</termVocabulary>
        <termVocabulary>Employee Status Global</termVocabulary>
        <termCategory>PDA</termCategory>
        <termCategory>PDI</termCategory>
        <termCategory>GLB</termCategory>
        <relation weight="100">
          <termId>49556</termId>
          <relationType>EQ</relationType>
          <termName>term name</termName>
          <termVocabulary>term vocabulary</termVocabulary>
        </relation>
        <relation weight="100">
          <termId>49556</termId>
          <relationType>BT</relationType>
          <termName>General Active Personnel</termName>
          <termVocabulary>People Status Global Updated</termVocabulary>
        </relation>
      </term>
      <term>
        <termId>49554</termId>
        <termUpdate>add</termUpdate>
        <termName>General Active Personnel</termName>
        <termVocabulary>People Status Global</termVocabulary>
        <termCategory>PDI</termCategory>
      </term>
    </Zthes>
  </FileData>
</GetSavedReportResponse>
```

here, there can be multiple termCategory tags for a term. I need to check if any of these  nodes contain a specified substring, if yes, I need to extract the entire term node. I tried like below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="termCategory">
      <xsl:if test="substring(FileData/Zthes/term/termCategory, 1, 2) = 'GL'">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="term"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, it is not working fine. Here the output should be:

```
<GetSavedReportResponse xmlns="">
  <ResponseType>Success</ResponseType>
  <FileModifiedDateTime>2012-01-03T17:05:04</FileModifiedDateTime>
  <FileSizeBytes>7816</FileSizeBytes>
  <FileDataFormat>XML</FileDataFormat>
  <FileData>
    <Zthes>
      <term>
        <termId>49555</termId>
        <termUpdate>add</termUpdate>
        <termName>Active Personnel</termName>
        <termVocabulary>People Status Global</termVocabulary>
        <termVocabulary>Employee Status Global</termVocabulary>
        <termCategory>PDA</termCategory>
        <termCategory>PDI</termCategory>
        <termCategory>GLB</termCategory>
        <relation weight="100">
          <relationType>EQ</relationType>
          <termName>term name</termName>
          <termVocabulary>term vocabulary</termVocabulary>
        </relation>
        <relation weight="100">
          <relationType>BT</relationType>
          <termName>General Active Personnel</termName>
          <termVocabulary>People Status Global Updated</termVocabulary>
        </relation>
      </term>
      <term>
    </Zthes>
  </FileData>
</GetSavedReportResponse>
```

p.s: The substring poistion is not fixed, so I cannot use startswith etc,. I must use SubString.
So, in the above eg: third termcategory of first term contains 'GL', hence it should be retrieved. The second term has one termCategory but does not contain 'GL', hence, it should not be retrieved. please help me where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You want to exclude from the output any `term` that hasn't a `termCategory`, whose string value starts with `"GL"`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="term[not(termCategory[starts-with(.,'GL')])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<GetSavedReportResponse xmlns="">
    <ResponseType>Success</ResponseType>
    <FileModifiedDateTime>2012-01-03T17:05:04</FileModifiedDateTime>
    <FileSizeBytes>7816</FileSizeBytes>
    <FileDataFormat>XML</FileDataFormat>
    <FileData>
        <Zthes>
            <term>
                <termId>49555</termId>
                <termUpdate>add</termUpdate>
                <termName>Active Personnel</termName>
                <termVocabulary>People Status Global</termVocabulary>
                <termVocabulary>Employee Status Global</termVocabulary>
                <termCategory>PDA</termCategory>
                <termCategory>PDI</termCategory>
                <termCategory>GLB</termCategory>
                <relation weight="100">
                    <relationType>EQ</relationType>
                    <termName>term name</termName>
                    <termVocabulary>term vocabulary</termVocabulary>
                </relation>
                <relation weight="100">
                    <relationType>BT</relationType>
                    <termName>General Active Personnel</termName>
                    <termVocabulary>People Status Global Updated</termVocabulary>
                </relation>
            </term>
            <term>
                <termId>49554</termId>
                <termUpdate>add</termUpdate>
                <termName>General Active Personnel</termName>
                <termVocabulary>People Status Global</termVocabulary>
                <termCategory>PDI</termCategory>
            </term>
        </Zthes>
    </FileData>
</GetSavedReportResponse>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<GetSavedReportResponse>
   <ResponseType>Success</ResponseType>
   <FileModifiedDateTime>2012-01-03T17:05:04</FileModifiedDateTime>
   <FileSizeBytes>7816</FileSizeBytes>
   <FileDataFormat>XML</FileDataFormat>
   <FileData>
      <Zthes>
         <term>
            <termId>49555</termId>
            <termUpdate>add</termUpdate>
            <termName>Active Personnel</termName>
            <termVocabulary>People Status Global</termVocabulary>
            <termVocabulary>Employee Status Global</termVocabulary>
            <termCategory>PDA</termCategory>
            <termCategory>PDI</termCategory>
            <termCategory>GLB</termCategory>
            <relation weight="100">
               <relationType>EQ</relationType>
               <termName>term name</termName>
               <termVocabulary>term vocabulary</termVocabulary>
            </relation>
            <relation weight="100">
               <relationType>BT</relationType>
               <termName>General Active Personnel</termName>
               <termVocabulary>People Status Global Updated</termVocabulary>
            </relation>
         </term>
      </Zthes>
   </FileData>
</GetSavedReportResponse>
```

**Explanation**:  Overriding the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** with a single template that matches any `term` that doesn't have a `termCategory` child whose value starts with the string `"GL"`. This overriding template has an empty body -- thus effectively excluding (deleting) from the output any matched node.

Comment: here the termCategory (I mean the tag name) (it can not be termCategory always), position of the string(start and length) are configurable. So, I need to check if the tag is the required one first, then, the substring. I tried, <xsl:template match="term[not(termCategory[substring(., 1, 2)])] = 'GL'"/>, but it gives an exception.

Comment: Updated. To give more insight, (i) & (ii) are two independent requirements. (i) only when the termId exists and contains some value within <termId>,</termId>, it should be retrieved. Or, if the tag does not exist or there is no value within the tags, DefaultTermId should be returned. (ii) 'GL' cannot always be starting string, so I need to check if the string contains 'GL' at the specified position, for that I thought substring should work. But, is gives an exception as said above.

Comment: @user1147759: You still haven't provided as part of the question, the exact wanted output from the transformation -- please, do so. The lack of this important information is the reason only two people responded.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but could it be that you want a

```
      <xsl:value-of select="relation/termId/text()" />
```

instead?

Though you don't have any `relation/termId` in your xml...

Also, in your second example you access `FileData` relative to `GetSavedReportResponse` node, not the `/` in which context you evaluate it.